# Can I use my own AttachedProperty as the StoryBoard.TargetProperty?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, focus, attached-properties

One of the controls in my view shall have the AttachedProperty "FocusClaim" set to true as soon as the VisualState "Prepared" is activated.
The msdn documentation says I'm allowed to use AttachedProperties, I just have to give ownerType and PropertyName in parenthesis. But doing so results in an Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: TargetProperty "(my:VisualStateMacro.FocusClaim)" cannot be resolved for the given object.

That's my VisualState with the animation:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Prepared">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Foo"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(my:VisualStateMacro.FocusClaim)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

And the actual target:
    `<TextBox my:VisualStateMacro.FocusClaim="False" x:Name="Foo"/>`

One line (found on msdn here [PropertyPath for Animation Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#databinding_sa) ) though somewhat clashes with the examples given on the same site:

> propertyName must be a property that exists on the type specified by Storyboard.TargetName.

And a few lines further down:

```
<animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ownerType.propertyName)" .../>
```

So am I allowed to use my own AttachedProperty as target or am I bound to use the properties that are present at the Control class?

This is how I defined my AttachedProperty:

```
public class VisualStateMacro
{
    public static bool GetFocusClaim( DependencyObject obj )
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue( FocusClaimProperty );
    }

    public static void SetFocusClaim( DependencyObject obj, bool value )
    {
        obj.SetValue( FocusClaimProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusClaimProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "FocusClaim", typeof( bool ),
                    typeof( VisualStateMacro ),
                    new PropertyMetadata( false, HandleFocusClaimChanged ) );

    private static void HandleFocusClaimChanged(
              DependencyObject d,
              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var focusTarget = d as Control;
        if(focusTarget==null)return;

        var shouldReceiveFocusNow = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (shouldReceiveFocusNow)
        {
            focusTarget.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```